# unable to pass a list from robot framework to python

Tags: python, python-3.6, robotframework

I need to pass a list from robot framework to python but I am unable to do that .

Kindly help in resolving the issue .

I have tried below mention robot code but it doesn't works :

```
${list1}= create list  a   b   c
${list2}= create list  d   e   f
cleanup1   ${list1}  ${list2}
```

python code :

```
def cleanup1(list1,list2):
    print (list1)
    print (list2)
```

Please help why is this failing ?

Expected output was to print both the list .

However I am getting error message :

No keyword with name ${list1}= create list found.

Comment: `${list1}= create list` found you need to add at least one more space after the `=` sign. Same for the second list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Robot uses two or more spaces to separate each component of a statement. You only have a single space between `${list1}=` and `create list`. Robot, therefore, thinks that the first cell is `${list1}= create list`. It expects to find either a variable or a keyword name in the first cell and it can't find a keyword named `${list1}= create list` so it throws the error that you are reporting.

The solution is simple: make sure there are two or more spaces between the variable and the keyword:

```
${list1}=  create list  a  b  c
         ^^
```